# When are images requested by the browser?

Tags: image, http, browser, browser-cache

I thought this would be an easy question to find an answer to, but I can't seem to find an answer.

I'm sure that this can vary with implementation. But generally speaking, for browsers for recent versions chrome, firefox, safari, ie. When are image requests sent to the server.

Is it as soon as a DOM element is parsed, or rendered, with a reference to an image? I'm assuming when the DOM is first rendered all referenced images are immediately fetched. Obviously the browser will check the cache first before requesting.

Does / How does this differ from images that are referenced in CSS?

Comment: It depends on the browser I beleive - http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Comment: Do you want to know all the situations that can cause a image to be requested or are you really asking about parse time (initial HTML load) behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the HTML-Tag is closed.

Assuming you have a HTML-Chat, the server may never close the stream and the DOM is never compleatly loaded, you will have this:

```
<body>
   <div id="content">
      <span class="smily">
         <img src="smily.png">
      </sp.....
```

Whearat ... defines data that currently not yet has reached the browser.

All css-rules can match, except the `:last-child` pseudo-class!

Indeed: the `simly.png` is requested after closing the `img`-tag.